# validating and counting selected checkbox values which come from subcategories.

Tags: php

I have created a form to display main categories and its subcategories. Everything in this form is creating dynamically. Why I use this form is to get subcategory values which selected from users. Here I use checkboxes for this purpose.

This is PHP I use for this..

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{cId:sId}' name='subcategory{$cId}[]' />{$sName}";
```

Then generating HTML something like this...

```
<h3>Main Category 01 
    <input type='checkbox' value='3:4' name='subcategory3[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='3:6' name='subcategory3[]' />sub category

<h3>Main Category 02 
    <input type='checkbox' value='4:6' name='subcategory4[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='4:2' name='subcategory4[]' />sub category

<h3>Main Category 01 
    <input type='checkbox' value='5:8' name='subcategory5[]' />sub category
    <input type='checkbox' value='5:4' name='subcategory5[]' />sub category
```

In this case you can see subcategory names generating dynamically. (subcategory3, subcategory4, subcategory5). Those values also may change according to the selected main category. Here I would like to know how I validate subcategory values with ISSET(). Because I dont know to detect what are values come from $_POST array..

Can someone help me out..

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that naming convention, you will have to parse the number out of the checkbox name:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if(strpos($key, 'subcategory') === 0 && is_array($value))
    {
        $subCategoryNumber = substr($key, 11);

        // loop over the values for this subcategory array:
        foreach($value as $checkboxValue)
        {
            echo 'subcategory checked: ' . $subCategoryNumber . ', value: ' . $checkboxValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of that, you could add a dimension to your array and use:

```
<input type='checkbox' value='3:4' name='subcategory[3][]' />sub category

<input type='checkbox' value='4:6' name='subcategory[4][]' />sub category

<input type='checkbox' value='5:8' name='subcategory[5][]' />sub category
```

This would mean you can access them in `$_POST['subcategory']` as an array:

```
foreach($_POST['subcategory'] as $key => $checkboxList)
{
    foreach($checkboxList as $checkboxValue)
    {
        echo 'subcategory checked: ' . $key . ', value: ' . $checkboxValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to check at least one subcategory has selected in each main category. And also need to limit upto 10 to select subcategories.. if these conditions not match need to display error masseges..

Comment: @TharangaNuwan in order to do that properly you will need an array of valid main and sub categories on the PHP side, that you can check against to do the validation.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend changing the name from `subcategory3[]` to `subcategory[3][]`.

After you do this, do a `var_dump($_POST['subcategory'])`, and you'll see how to information is sent, you will have the full information in a single array.

Other than this, not sure what your problem could be, can you be a bit more specific on where you're having trouble?